# Why don't we get custodian if someone else edits our post?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Why can't we get the *custodian* badge if **someone with a high reputation edits our post**? And if we review those suggested edits (which are from basically low reputation OP), we get the *custodian* badge.

Comment: Your post is making work for people, you should not be rewarded for it.

Comment: IMO these kind of questions you need to flip upside down. You ask others: why don't you. You should ask yourself: why should you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Custodian badge:

> Complete at least one [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) task. This badge is awarded once per review type

You didn't complete a review task (there isn't one, because high-rep users' edits are not reviewed), so you don't get the badge.  Why would you?